# Two players are playing a game against each other repeatedly until one runs out of money. Gambler's ruin

Tags: probability, random-variables

Two players are playing a game against each other repeatedly until one runs out of money. When a player wins a game they take 1 dollar from the other player. All plays of the game are independent and identical. 
Suppose player A starts with 2 dollars and player B starts with 1 dollar. If player A wins a game with probability p, what is the probability that player A wins all the money?

My Solution: P(A wins a game) = p

P(B wins a game)= 1-p = q

Want probability B ends up with no money.
Thus $1-(q /p)^{n_1}$/ $1-(q/p)^{n_1+n_2}$

where $n_1$=2 and $n_2=1$

Part B: Assume each player has 6$ to begin with and p=q=0.5 probability of winning. What is the probability the someone loses all money on exactly the tenth game?
I'm not sure how I would approach this since p=q and that just makes my equation = 0/0

Comment: If $p=q =\frac12$ and $A$ starts with $\$a$ and $B$ starts with $\$b$ then the probability $A$ wins all the money is $\frac{a}{a+b}$ with an easy induction proof

Comment: @Henry - That's a neat result...  what do you induct on?  The sum $a+b$?

Comment: Maybe saying a recursion would be better.  Anyway, you get $P_{0,a+b}=0$ and $P_{a+1,b-1}-P_{a,b}=\frac qp(P_{a,b}-P_{a-1,b+1})$ and $P_{a+b,1}=1$.  With $p=q$ this becomes  $P_{a+1,b-1}-P_{a,b}=P_{a,b}-P_{a-1,b+1}$ so $a+b$ equal gaps adding up to $1$ this leads to $P_{a,b}=\frac{a}{a+b}$.  In effect the geometric sum that leads to your result is easier though different when the common ratio is $1$